# Webview Doesn't Operate on Existing Code Prints The Error Below Oreo

Tags: java, android, webview, android-bitmap, android-8.0-oreo

Below error appears when trying to open a video employing webview. Weird thing is, same code works on a different project. This only happens on android 8.0 OREO

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference


E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.mobisoft.flyco, PID: 11628
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:585)
                                                                    at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

CODE SNIPPET

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
WebSettings 
webSettings = webView.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.loadUrl("youtube.com/watch?v=D7LB-QPxH9c");
```

Comment: share the code snip.

Comment: I have added my snip and used a youtube video link as an example. This code crashes in one project but doesnt on another.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like you have run into a bug. Anything in the bug trackers already?

Comment: Nothing and that's the issue. I only receive above error.